# Why would there be a larger data dispersion at minimums than at maximums in a graph of intensity against path difference?

Tags: waves, experimental-physics, superposition, intensity

I'm doing a rather simple experiment concerning the superposition of two waves and the impact that path difference of 2 identical waves has on recorded intensity at that point. However, there is pattern in my data of values being significantly more dispersed at the points of destructive interference than at points of constructive interference. Anyone knows a physical explanation of why that could be?

Comment: It would help if you gave details of the experimental set up including the sensor used for the data capture and a visual presentation of your observations.

Answer (score 0):

**Note** : As I don't have much information about the experiment you are talking about, I present here a potential cause but it is quite general. If this answer does not suit you, I invite you to edit your question with more details.

The dispersion of the recorded intensity of waves during destructive interference may be due to the presence of background noise or extraneous sources that cause fluctuations in the wave intensities. The phase difference between the two waves at the point of destructive interference is 180 degrees, which means that the two waves are exactly out of phase and tend to cancel each other out. The resulting intensity at this point is therefore much lower compared to other points. The lower intensity of the waves can make it more sensitive to external disturbances and more prone to fluctuations, leading to the observed pattern of increased dispersion at the points of destructive interference.

In contrast, at the points of constructive interference, the phase difference between the two waves is an even multiple of 180 degrees, which means that the two waves are in phase and reinforce each other. The resulting intensity at these points is higher and less sensitive to external disturbances, which can lead to more consistent and less dispersed intensity measurements.